# Does ArcGIS Collector capture device metadata?

Tags: metadata, arcgis-collector

Does ArcGIS Collector capture device metadata along with observed data ie. actual device location, system date, GPS accuracy?

Comment: Define device metadata please. Like what? Have you checked the terms and conditions for ESRI collector?

Answer (score 1):

-Accuracy is collected only on the tracking layer
-Date can be automatically collected if you are using editor tracking fields. The date here will probably be in UTC.
-No x,y info is added automatically to fields for points, you would have to run the Add XY GP tool after to add that to fields